# incomprehensible behavior of this

Tags: vala

I have few problems dealing with the behavior of this in vala class.

here is my code: (build_and_send1 and build_and_send2 are signals raised by pressing a button)

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;

public class Main : Object 
{

    /* 
     * Uncomment this line when you are done testing and building a tarball
     * or installing
     */
    //const string UI_FILE = Config.PACKAGE_DATA_DIR + "/" + "gtk_httpclient.ui";
    const string UI_FILE = "src/gtk_httpclient.ui";

    /* ANJUTA: Widgets declaration for gtk_httpclient.ui - DO NOT REMOVE */


    private Builder builder;

    public Main ()
    {

        try 
        {
            this.builder = new Builder ();
            this.builder.add_from_file (UI_FILE);
            this.builder.connect_signals (this);

            var window = this.builder.get_object ("window") as Window;
            /* ANJUTA: Widgets initialization for gtk_httpclient.ui - DO NOT REMOVE */
            window.show_all ();

            stderr.printf ("constructor:\n");
            stderr.printf ("this: %p\n", this);
            stderr.printf ("builder: %p\n", this.builder);
        } 
        catch (Error e) {
            stderr.printf ("Could not load UI: %s\n", e.message);
        } 

    }

    [CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
    public void on_destroy (Widget window) 
    {
        Gtk.main_quit();
    }

    public void build_and_send1 (Widget button)
    {
        stderr.printf ("\nbuild_and_send1:\n");
        stderr.printf ("this: %p\n", this);
        stderr.printf ("builder: %p\n", this.builder);
    }

    [CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
    public void build_and_send2 (Widget button)
    {
        stderr.printf ("\nbuild_and_send2:\n");
        stderr.printf ("this: %p\n", this);
        stderr.printf ("builder: %p\n", this.builder);
    }

    static int main (string[] args) 
    {
        Gtk.init (ref args);
        new Main ();

        Gtk.main ();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've got this output :

```
constructor:
this: 0x1a524a0
builder: 0x1a6a230

build_and_send1:
this: 0x1aa2030
builder: 0x5a4fe823

build_and_send2:
this: 0x1a524a0
Program has been terminated receiving signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
```

I assume that if I want the same instance of Main in my signals, they have to be preceded by [CCode (instance_pos = -1)].
But then what is th goal of **builder.connect_signals (this);** ?

And why this.builder raises a segmentation fault in **build_and_send2** and not in the **constructor** ?

Comment: by the way I'm using Anjuta 3.6.2 and Glade 3.14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the result of `new Main()` is going out of scope after construction and being garbage collected. Assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I've solved my problem declaring builder as static variable.

Answer (score 0):

I understand a little bit more how this is working.

In my project I made a UIHandler class to handled UI events.

When I connect the instance of this class inside its constructor it doesn't work, but if I connect the instance outside the class it works fine.

Wrong: this will terminate with a segmentation fault.

```
// Constructor
public UIHandler (Builder builder) {
    var button = builder.get_object ("send-button") as Button;
    Object (button: button);

    bulder.connect_signals (this);
}
...
[CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
public void activate (Entry location) {
    this.button.clicked ();
}
```

Correct: This will wroks.

Main class:

```
public Main ()
{

    try 
    {
        var builder = new Builder ();
        builder.add_from_file (UI_FILE);

        builder.connect_signals (new UIHandler (builder));

        var window = builder.get_object ("window") as Window;

        /* ANJUTA: Widgets initialization for gtk_http_client.ui - DO NOT REMOVE */
        window.show_all ();
    } 
    catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("Could not load UI: %s\n", e.message);
    } 

}
```

UIHandler Class:

```
// Constructor
public UIHandler (Builder builder) {
    var button = builder.get_object ("send-button") as Button;
    Object (button: button);
}
...
[CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
public void activate (Entry location) {
    this.button.clicked ();
}
```

This behavoir solves my original issue.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding why that works.  It comes down to the fact that Gtk.Builder.connect_signals takes a void*.  Vala currently pretty much ignores memory management when you pass a value to a pointer, so the parameter will act like either an owned parameter or an unowned parameter depending on what you pass it.  Since you're creating a new instance of UIHandler in the connect_signals call, Vala treats it as an owned parameter.  You could achieve a similar effect in the UIHandler constructor by using "(owned)" to transfer a reference, or calling GLib.Object.ref manually.

Comment: I read about owned and unowned instance just after posting this response. You confirm my thought. Thx for the explanation, I will try it later.